# Otimizar uma transferência de dados de uma tabela para outra SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, sql-insert

Banco SQL SERVER
Tenho duas tabelas, uma com 2 bilhões de registros e outra com 16 bilhões. Estou copiando a primeira para a segunda.

Usando o

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Não funciona porque o log gerado estoura meu HD.

Fiz o bloco sql com a seguinte lógica:

```
/*** Sql para juntar o conteúdo das tabela lote4 e carga*/
USE [bd_contagem]
GO
BEGIN
-- Incluindo as informações na tabela temporaria

DECLARE @lote_XXX float
DECLARE @numero_contrato nvarchar(255) 
DECLARE @codigo_equipamento nvarchar(255) 
DECLARE @sentido nvarchar(255)
DECLARE @faixa float
DECLARE @data_contagem date
DECLARE @hora time
DECLARE @classe float
DECLARE @veloc float
DECLARE @v_cont float = 0
declare @vcont_qte_inseridas float
declare @dia int
declare @mes int
declare @ano int
declare @dia_semana int
declare @id_equipamento int

DECLARE crLerLote4 CURSOR FOR
SELECT  '4','TT-954/2010-00'
      ,[codigo_equipamento]
      ,SUBSTRING( [faixa],3,1) AS SENTINDO
      ,SUBSTRING( [faixa],5,1) AS FAIXA
      ,[data_contagem]
      ,[hora]
      ,[classe]
      ,[veloc]
      ,[id_equipamento]
      ,[dia]
      ,[mes]
      ,[ano]
      ,[dia_semana]
  FROM [bd_contagem].[dbo].[tblVMDcargaLote4]

OPEN crLerLote4

FETCH NEXT FROM crLerLote4 INTO
        @lote_XXX,  @numero_contrato,@codigo_equipamento,@sentido,  @faixa,
        @data_contagem,@hora,@classe,@veloc,@id_equipamento,@dia,@mes,@ano,
        @dia_semana

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            INSERT INTO [bd_contagem].[dbo].tblVMDcarga
                        (lote_XXX
                        ,numero_contrato
                        ,codigo_equipamento
                        ,sentido
                        ,faixa
                        ,data_contagem
                        ,hora
                        ,classe
                        ,veloc
                        ,id_equipamento
                        ,dia
                        ,mes
                        ,ano
                        ,dia_semana)
                 VALUES
                       (@lote_XXX,
                        @numero_contrato,
                        @codigo_equipamento, 
                        @sentido,
                        @faixa,
                        @data_contagem,
                        @hora,
                        @classe,
                        @veloc,
                        @id_equipamento,
                        @dia,
                        @mes,
                        @ano,
                        @dia_semana)

            delete [bd_contagem].[dbo].[tblVMDcargaLote4]
              where codigo_equipamento = @codigo_equipamento
                  and data_contagem = @data_contagem
                  and hora = @hora
                  and classe = @classe
                  and veloc = @veloc
                  and id_equipamento = @id_equipamento


        FETCH NEXT FROM crLerLote4 INTO
            @lote_XXX,  @numero_contrato,@codigo_equipamento,@sentido,  @faixa,
            @data_contagem,@hora,@classe,@veloc,@id_equipamento,@dia,@mes,@ano,
            @dia_semana

        --set @v_cont = @v_cont + 1  
        --print @v_cont
        IF (@@ERROR = 0)
        BEGIN
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END
    END
    CLOSE crLerLote4
    DEALLOCATE crLerLote4
END
```

Este processo está copiando em média 15.000 registros por segundo.

Se eu rodo o mesmo bloco duas vezes, percebo que a performance não melhora.

Preciso melhorar esta performance, e gostaria de saber se há alguma sugestão de solução melhor.

Comment: E em questão de Hardware não teria como haver um melhoramento, por exemplo, aumentando sua capacidade de processamento

Comment: Eu aconselho a você não utilizar o cursor para isso, ele é muito lento, o ideal seria vc fazer um SELECT INSERT, dessa forma seria muito mais rápido

Comment: Você tem um problema interessante nas mãos. Adianto que CURSOR é uma escolha péssima para seu caso, pois trata-se de muitos registros. O que você pode fazer é desativar a geração de transaction log, fazer o que precisa ser feito e ativar novamente.

Comment: Só um detalhe importante: o fato de usar CURSOR não vai fazer com que o log não seja gerado. O HD só não lotou porque o CURSOR é ordens de magnitude mais lento do que o INSERT SELECT. Portanto, se você deixar o CURSOR rodando tempo suficiente o seu HD vai estourar também.

Comment: @CirineuLacerdaBraga: Qual é o modelo de recuperação? // Qual é a versão do SQL Server? // Qual é a chave primária da tabela [bd_contagem].[dbo].[tblVMDcargaLote4]? // O banco de dados pode ser colocado em monousuário enquanto a movimentação de linhas é realizada? // Todas as linhas da tabela tblVMDcargaLote4 são de um mesmo lote/contrato?

Comment: @CirineuLacerdaBraga: Cuidado com o uso de variáveis float, nesse caso. Me refiro às variáveis @ lote_XXX, @ sentido e @ faixa, que recebem 1 caractere como conteúdo. Porquê não declarar como char(1) ou, melhor ainda, da mesma forma que estão declaradas na tabela de destino (tblVMDcarga)?

Comment: @CirineuLacerdaBraga: Para reduzir o tamanho do arquivo de log, sugiro que retire o comando DELETE tblVMDcargaLote4, ficando somente a parte de cópia (INSERT into INTO tblVMDcarga). // Para apagar o conteúdo da tabela tblVMDcargaLote4, é mais eficiente (em termos de reduzir log) executar o TRUNCATE tblVMDcargaLote4 ao final (somente após a transferência ser considerada correta).

Comment: @JoséDiz Com o TRUNCATE ele não pode usar a clausula WHERE como esta fazendo o DELETE. A melhor opção é desativar a geração de LOG e fazer o INSERT SELECT ou talvez, não tenho como testar com essa quantidade de dados, usar o BULK INSERT.

Answer (score 2):

Cirineu, pelo que você relata o problema é que, durante a execução do primeiro código T-SQL descrito, todo o espaço disponível no disco é utilizado, antes mesmo que a execução do código termine, abortando o processo de transferência de linhas entre as tabelas. E menciona como possível causa o crescimento do log de transações.

Pelo nome das colunas presentes em tblVMDcarga, bem como pelo nome da tabela, me parece que é uma tabela de carga (ETL) de uma tabela fato de *data warehouse*, provavelmente de contagem de tráfego do DNIT.

São necessárias informações adicionais para emitir opinião específica; como ainda não foram fornecidas, seguem observações gerais.

---

> **Modelos de recuperação**

Conforme documentação do SQL Server, "*[modelos de recuperação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189275.aspx) são projetados para controlar a manutenção de log de transações*". 
Pela leitura da documentação percebe-se como a definição do modelo de recuperação impacta diretamente no volume de log gerado.

---

> ***minimal logging***

A respeito do log de transações, há uma abordagem que é denominada de *minimal logging*. Ela está descrita em alguns documentos do SQL Server, como:

- [Operations That Can Be Minimally Logged](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244.aspx)
- [The Transaction Log](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server)
- [Prerequisites for Minimal Logging in Bulk Import](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/prerequisites-for-minimal-logging-in-bulk-import)

Há alguns requisitos para obter sucesso nessa abordagem, que estão descritos nos documentos acima. Observe que a construção INSERT...SELECT também é considerada uma operação *bulk import*.

---

> **tempDB**

É necessário ficar atento à configuração do banco de dados tempDB, para que este não se transforme em gargalo. Sugiro leitura do artigo [How to Configure TempDB for Microsoft SQL Server](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/01/cheat-sheet-how-to-configure-tempdb-for-microsoft-sql-server/)

---

> **Execução em paralelo**

Outro fator que deve ser analisado com atenção é como está configurado, na instância, a opção [*max degree of parallelism*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-server-configuration-option).

---

> **VLT (*very large tables*)**

No caso de tabelas VLT, uma das opções utilizadas para transferir linhas de uma tabela para outra é realizar a cópia em blocos. Isto é, transfere-se um pedaço de cada vez. A definição do conteúdo/tamanho de cada bloco depende do contexto.

Para utilizar a transferência por blocos de forma eficiente é necessário que na tabela de origem exista identificação única (unique key) que permita identificar o que já foi transferido. No caso de tabelas fato, geralmente é utilizada [*surrogate key*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). Por questão de performance, é recomendado que exista índice pela identificação única, preferencialmente *clustered*.

Supondo que deseja-se transferir milhões de linhas da tabela stageDADOS para a tabela DADOS e que a chave primária da tabela stageDADOS seja a coluna idEvento. Pode-se implementar a transferência de blocos utilizando algo semelhante a

```
-- código #1
INSERT into DADOS (colunas)
    SELECT colunas
      from stageDADOS
      where idEvento between ....
```

A cada execução do código acima, transfere-se um bloco de linhas. Deve-se manter controle de qual foi a última linha transferida em cada execução, para que a próxima execução seja da primeira linha ainda não transferida.

Ou seja, com a abordagem acima é possível transferir bloco a bloco e monitorar o crescimento do arquivo de log.

Segue exemplo com implementação dessa abordagem.

```
-- código #2
CREATE TABLE stageDADOS (
   idEvento int identity primary key, 
   dataEvento date not null,
   infoEvento varchar(200) not null
);

CREATE TABLE DADOS (
   idEvento int not null, 
   dataEvento date not null,
   infoEvento varchar(200) not null
);
go
```

Observa-se que a tabela DADOS é do tipo [*heap*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh213609.aspx).

Para controle do que já foi transferido, é criada a tabela ControleTransf no banco de dados. Ela permitirá manter o controle do que já foi transferido, bem como emissão de estatísticas sobre o processo de transferência.

```
-- código #3
CREATE TABLE ControleTransf (
   idBloco int identity, 
   inicioTransf smalldatetime not null, 
   fimTransf smalldatetime default cast(current_timestamp as smalldatetime),
   nLinhas int,
   chaveInicial int, 
   chaveFinal int
);
go
```

E, finalmente, o procedimento que efetua a transferência de um bloco de linhas.

```
-- código #4
CREATE PROCEDURE TransfBloco @tamBloco int as
begin
declare @ultimaChave int, @chaveInicial int, @chaveFinal int;
declare @inicioTransf smalldatetime, @nLinhas int;

-- procura última chave transferida
SELECT top (1) @ultimaChave= chaveFinal
  from ControleTransf
  order by idBloco desc;
set @ultimaChave= coalesce(@ultimaChave, 0);

-- define chaves inicial e final do bloco
set @chaveInicial= @ultimaChave + 1;
set @chaveFinal= @ultimaChave + @tamBloco;

-- 
set @inicioTransf= cast(current_timestamp as smalldatetime);

--
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

BEGIN TRY

-- transfere bloco
INSERT into DADOS with (TABLOCK) (idEvento, dataEvento, infoEvento) 
    SELECT idEvento, dataEvento, infoEvento
      from stageDADOS
      where idEvento >= @chaveInicial
            and idEvento <= @chaveFinal;

-- 
set @nLinhas= @@rowcount;

-- registra bloco transferido
IF @nLinhas > 0
  begin
  INSERT into ControleTransf (chaveInicial, chaveFinal, inicioTransf, nLinhas)
         values (@chaveInicial, @chaveFinal, @inicioTransf, @nLinhas);
  SELECT 'Transferidas ' + cast(@nLinhas as varchar(15)) + ' linhas.' as Status;
  end
else
  SELECT 'Nenhuma linha transferida.' as Status;    

-- encerra transação explícita
COMMIT; 

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH;
SELECT 'erro na transferência' as Status;
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH;
end;
go
```

A execução é simples. Considera-se que o modelo de recuperação do banco de dados está como *bulk-logged*. Para transferir 100 milhões de linhas, basta chamar o procedimento TransfBloco, passando como parâmetro o número de linhas.

```
-- código #5 v2
-- transfere um bloco de linhas
EXECUTE dbo.TransfBloco 100000000
-- monitora ocupação de espaço físico
EXECUTE sp_spaceused 'DADOS';
DBCC SQLPERF (logspace);
go
```

Sugiro que inicie por bloco de tamanho menor (10 milhões de linhas, por exemplo). Terá então informações sobre performance, tempo e alocação de espaço físico para esse tamanho de bloco, podendo então definir qual será o tamanho de bloco ideal para cada execução.

A abordagem acima pode ser modificada para caso a coluna de chave primária seja, por exemplo, do tipo [*uniqueidentifier*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187942.aspx).

---

> **RBAR**

[RBAR](https://www.google.com.br/search?client=ubuntu&q=sql%20server%20rbar&tbs=qdr:y) é a abreviatura da expressão Row-By-Agonizing-Row, cunhada por [Jeff Moden](https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/PublicProfile/4020758?fullName=Jeff%20Moden) para códigos que processam uma linha de cada vez. Sempre que possível devemos construir códigos que manipulem conjunto de linhas (*set-based*), que é de processamento mais eficiente no SQL Server. Entretanto, há (poucas) situações em que o uso de cursor é mais eficiente do que o uso de construções *set-based*.

No segundo código fornecido, com o uso de cursor, percebe-se a presença de uma abordagem RBAR. E, nesse caso, me parece extremamente ineficiente. Além de transferir linha a linha, da tabela de origem para a tabela de destino, ainda há o agravante de que o conteúdo da tabela de origem também é apagado linha a linha. Ou seja, pode aumentar mais rapidamente o arquivo de log (vide modelos de recuperação).

---

> **Otimização do código com cursor**

(1) Em termos de arquivo de log, considero mais eficiente apagar manualmente a tabela de origem ao final (quando a transferência for considerada correta), seja através de comando DROP TABLE (caso a tabela de origem não seja mais necessária) ou de comando TRUNCATE TABLE.

O fato de ir apagando linha a linha na tabela de origem não significa que o espaço físico será liberado imediatamente pelo sgbd.

Mas, caso julgue necessário apagar linha a linha, observe que pode-se apagar a linha corrente do cursor sem necessidade de que a instrução DELETE realize nova pesquisa (o que demanda mais tempo de processamento). Basta utilizar CURRENT OF:

```
-- código #6
DELETE [bd_contagem].[dbo].[tblVMDcargaLote4]
  where current of crLerLote4;
```

(2) Ao [declarar um cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms180169.aspx) há opções que, teoricamente, podem otimizar a execução do mesmo. Leitura atenta da documentação pode indicar possíveis opções a utilizar.

Comment: Obrigado José, todas suas observações foram pertinentes. Como é só uma vez que vou precisar fazer isto a solução do Reginaldo será mais prática para mim.

Answer (score 1):

Aqui vai uma possibilidade:

Crie um arquivo bat com seguinte conteúdo.

Altere as váriaveis para seu ambiente.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET banco=DATABASENAME
SET pasta_destino=C:\ARQUIVOS
SET servidor=SERVERNAME
SET instance=SQLEXPRESS2008r2
SET username=USERNAME
SET password=secreta


bcp "SELECT * FROM %banco%..TABLE1" queryout %pasta_destino%\table1.csv -S%servidor%\%instance% -U%username% -P%password% -t; -c
```

Isso vai gerar o arquivo `TABLE1.CSV` na pasta C:\ARQUIVOS

Agora rode o seguinte comando no SQL-Server para importar os registros para a 
tabela2

```
BULK INSERT dbo.TABLE2
FROM 'C:\ARQUIVOS\table1.csv'
WITH
(
     FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

Comment: Obrigado Reginaldo. Funcionou com menos da metade do tempo que estava esperando com o meu cursor.

Comment: Eu já sabia que esse processo com bcp e bulk insert seria rápido, mas nunca testei com essa quantidade de registros. Poderia nos dizer quanto tempo demorou cada processo e aceitar a resposta? rsrs